# C++ multithreading to process multiple customer carts simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am required to process many shopping carts in front of many queues using multithreading. I created a container for database from a given file holds strings barocdes, item name, and price. Also created a container for customer carts from given file that holds strigns cart number and barcode of items. The requirement is to lock the process when scanning a single item only NOT the whole items of a cart to let other queues process their cart then printing the receipts. I put mutex lock before and after scanning statement but failed to store each cart items separated on other carts. I set everything well but the process function I have an issue with, becasue the receipts I got has a mess or truncated. I am new with multithreading concepts and spent long time with is code but I stuck and I need an advise of what is wrong on my function. Thanks in advance.

```
     #include <fstream>
     #include <cstdlib>
     #include <string>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <vector>
     #include <regex>
     #include <algorithm>
     #include <tuple>
     #include <bitset>
     #include <math.h>
     #include <sstream>
     #include <unordered_map>
     #include <condition_variable>
     #include <thread>
     #include <mutex>
     #include <queue>
     #include <iomanip>

      using namespace std;

     std::mutex dataBaseMut;

 
//********************************************
class cartManager
{
    
    //this function parametes are database and SINGLE queue
    void processCarts(const unordered_map<string, pair<string, string>>& 
          dataBase
        , queue<pair<string, vector<string>>>& singleQue)
    {
         // deque to hold cartNo, itemName, and price
        string totalPrice = "";
        string cartNo;
        string cartItem;
        string itemPrice;
        string barcode;
        bool errorFlag = false;;
        
        //if signle queue is not empty, then process the carts
        while (!singleQue.empty())
        {
            int frontCartSize;
            //detemine the queue size
            int singleQueSzie = singleQue.size(); 
            //get cartNo of cart that is in front of deque
            cartNo = singleQue.front().first; 
            int j = 0;
            //get cartSize of cart that is in front of deque
            frontCartSize = singleQue.front().second.size(); 
            // process in front cart items till end of items
            for (; j < frontCartSize; j++) 
            {
                string notfound = " ";
                stringstream items;

                dataBaseMut.lock();
                // search barode of an item in data base
                auto it = dataBase.find(singleQue.front().second[j]);

                 //if not found then search it in errorlog

                if (it == dataBase.end()) 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < errorLogProducts.size(); i++)
                    {
                     if (errorLogProducts[i] == singleQue.front().second[j])
                      {
                        string cartItem = singleQue.front().second[j];
                        
                            errorFlag = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else // if found,then get info of the item from data base 
                {
                    cartNo = singleQue.front().first; // get cart number
                    cartItem = it->second.first;   // get item name
                    itemPrice = it->second.second; //get item price

                    //push all above into a vector 
                    cartNo_Item_Price.push_back(make_tuple(cartNo, 
                   make_pair(cartItem, itemPrice)));
                }
                dataBaseMut.unlock();
                //if you reach the end of items of a cart, then remove it from deque


                if (j == singleQue.front().second.size() - 1)
                {
                    singleQue.pop(); // remove processed cart
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //********************************
    
};


     
[![top of receipt][1]][1]


[![bottom of receipt][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wouq6.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq5tT.png
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code, minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan The whole code is long and I made sure very well that the dataBase and all_queues are set correctly. My main code work starts from filling threads vector. Thank you –

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan thanks for trying to help. I pasted my whole code. I have issue with my void processCarts() because I need each single carts queue be processed by a single thread simultaneously with other queues threads and printing receipts separated. I need to protect data base and lock it but when I do that I get mess in receipts

Comment: In `processCarts` you pass `dataBase` and `singleQue` by value, not a reference (a new copy of it is created each time you create a thread), thus they should not be synchronized. But I suppose it's different from what you expect. Btw, did you read my answer above regarding the issue with `outFile`? That is an issue and should be fixed anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688989/6232365

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan. Thanks for reading my code to help. I used to send `dataBase` and `singleQue` by reference but changed it. I did the changes based on your answer and protected `outFile` by mutex but unfortunately, I have little truncation in my receipts. Will attach supposed receipts and what I got

Comment: I deleted some parts of my code for now because it is an assignment and maybe one copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your main you create a new cartManager for each thread. I believe it is not what you did on purpose.

   threads.emplace_back
   (
   &cartManager::processCarts, cartManager(),
   ref(dataBase), ref(all_queues[q])
   );

Instead of passing `cartManager()` pass `&manager`. Why it is important? Because of creating a brand new `cartManager` for each thread, your function has a different `this` context. That means, all your threads has its own dataBaseMut - so nothing is synchronized between your threads because of that!

2. You don't need to modify `dataBase` in `processCarts` - in that case, pass it by `const` reference: in that case, it's obvious to other people (and to you) that it is not something that may be modified in `processCarts`.
3. Now opening the file is synchronized (in case you fix the very first issue I described in this answer), but only opening! Writing to the file is not synchronized, so there is a chance that your threads write to the same file simultaneously. What may happen in that case? A mess! Thus, not only opening the file should be synchronized, but writing as well. I would suggest creating a class that is in charge of writing to a file and is thread safe (it's safe to call its methods from different threads). And that class would take care of synchronizing the access to a file.

Comment: I have applied the changes you suggested but still have issues with receipts like there are duplicated carts like cart437 but my receipt shows only one cart and some other issues. I am going to post the changes and please, advise if I have something wrong. 1- did this change in main(), 2- only passed ~dataBase` by ref because `singleQue` I have to pop out completed cart. 3- created class to print receipt inside `cartManager`. Thanks in advance

Comment: just a note, I deleted some parts from my code above because it is an assignment and maybe somebody copy it.

Comment: @Code_Student please update your question by attaching the latest result that you have. I still see a problem even in your updated source code, but it'd better to see the result at first.

Comment: @Code_Student You put the writing part into a separate class, but you still open the file from different threads. It can cause a mess in your file, and it's absolutely pointless. Why don't you open the file in your `writeReceipts`?

Comment: Thanks for your patience to help me with the assignment. I have updated the code and posted it again and used `writeReceipts` separate to print the receipts but I got receipt printing all items of all cart queues under front cart487 which in the first queue and total price got accumulated of all carts in queues!

Comment: I beg your pardon, can I contact you in a direct way, if you like. I have googled and YouTubed many and I know I am lacking full knowledge of Thread-topic because we just covered that in 3 weeks ago the teacher lecture is not that helpful. Thank you so much again.

Comment: by the way, I update main() too after using `writeReceipts`. Thank you

Comment: @Code_Student you can share your contacts with me here, and I will contact you if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250282/discussion-between-code-student-and-arman-oganesyan).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your comments got me close to completing my assignment. I put many messages in private chat but didn't get a response but I could figure out what was the logical error. It is fixed and working. Thanks.

Comment: @Code_Student hello. I am really sorry about that, I forgot about stackoverflow for a while :( Regarding the private chat - I haven't received any email notifications regarding it :( If you still have any question - please, ask them here. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the whole source code, but what is wrong in your code is that opening of your file `outFile` is not protected by your mutex. This should be a reason why you have a mess in your file.

Comment: I applied the changes in the code above based on your last answer